# Combination of angular and linear acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I was wondering how the angular and linear acceleration of a body in free fall interacted with each other. Let's imagine a man as a yoyo spinning around a string in free fall. It will have two accelerations, one angular and one linear. How is linear acceleration affected by angular acceleration?
The linear acceleration is due $$\sum_{ext} F=T-mg.$$
Angular acceleration is due to the tension in the string and the friction between the string and the man:
We have a torque due to gravity but I can not express mathematically what happens.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chC7xVDKl4Q

Comment: A yo-yo is not a good example here because it has rather complicated dynamics when considering the general motion.

Answer (score 0):

The equations of motion on a plane still hold for a body like a yo-yo

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_x & = m\, \ddot{x}_C \\
  F_y & = m\, \ddot{y}_C \\
  \tau_C & = I_C \alpha
\end{aligned}$$

where $F_x$ is the net force acting on the body along the *x*-axis, $F_y$ the net force acting on the body along the *y*-axis, $\tau_C$ the net torque (including the effect of the forces) about the center of mass, $m$ the mass of the body, $\ddot{x}_C$ is the acceleration of the center of mass *x*-coordinate, $\ddot{y}_C$ is the acceleration of the center of mass *y*-coordinate, and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the body.